# Has anyone else encountered a bug with SimpleDateFormat.format method where it returns a wrong year?

Tags: java

I am using Oracle java 1.7.0_45 and it appears that SimpleDateFormat.format method returns 2015 for the year component instead of 2014.

Here is the unit test:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Test {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMMdd");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date today = new Date();
        System.out.println("OS: " + System.getProperty("os.name") + " " + System.getProperty("os.version"));
        System.out.println("Java Vendor: " + System.getProperty("java.vendor"));
        System.out.println("Java Version: " + System.getProperty("java.version"));
        System.out.println("Today: " + today.toString() + " formatted: " + DATE_FORMAT.format(today));
    }
}
```

And here is the output from the unit test:
    OS: Mac OS X 10.10.1
    Java Vendor: Oracle Corporation
    Java Version: 1.7.0_45
    Today: Mon Dec 29 09:43:00 EST 2014 formatted: 20151229

Comment: What is the date pattern `YYYY`?

Comment: Instead of claiming a bug, did you first read the doc of `SimpleDateFormat`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
```

yyyy and YYYY are different, as MM and mm are.

Answer (score 1):

pattern used - `yyyyMMdd`

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Test {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date today = new Date();
        System.out.println("Java Vendor: " + System.getProperty("java.vendor"));
        System.out.println("Java Version: " + System.getProperty("java.version"));
        System.out.println("Today: " + today.toString() + " formatted: " + DATE_FORMAT.format(today));
    }
}
```

**output**

```
Java Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java Version: 1.6.0_31
Today: Mon Dec 29 20:21:17 IST 2014 formatted: 20141229
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `yyyyMMdd` in stead. `YYYY` is for `week Year` ([see javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)) which might, depending on your `Locale`, sometimes return the 53rd week of the past year when using early jan dates or the 1st week of the new year when using late december dates.